# How to place an event for multiple items?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a doubt. All right. I have a post in which users post comments and next to each post have a button belonging to each of them. Well, as I get when I click on each of these buttons me out a popup.

With that event ?. An event for several elements. But that is the same for all those buttons.

ahhh. These buttons are generated or printed with php, when the user posts something, that something has a button. Help!!!

**HTML**

```
<a id="popup" class="globes_post_giving">♠</a>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#popup").on({ click:function(e){
            alert('hola');
        } }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: @LifeTimeProgrammer I have the HTML code and a little of jquery:        <a id="popup" class="globes_post_giving">♠</a>

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#popup").on({
    click:function(e){alert('hola');}

    
  });
});

</script>

Comment: Please see [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery code seems not good.

There are syntaxes errors.

Here is my two cents :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#popup").click(function(e){
            alert('hola');
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

In order to be used with multiple buttons you'd better use a class instead of an id and set the click event on it.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="popup">First link</a>
<a href="#" class="popup">Second link</a>
<a href="#" class="popup">Third link</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".popup").click(function(e){
        alert('hola');
    }); 
});
```

That's all I can do without more code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Like I said, to be used with severals elements, you'd better use class instead of id.

Comment: @luis see my edited answer for an example of class use for severals elements.

Comment: ok.is working now.But when i want to click on a button the content get placed in the same place,the first post.

Comment: I used Position:absolute

Comment: You mean, the alert popup from js ?

Comment: Please if it answer your question, you can click on the green tic to validate it. ; ) Also, I made an edit of your Question. Accept it please for other users that may read this post.